# How can i play mp4 file from DCIM folder?

Tags: android, video, mp4, internal-storage

i am creating simple android app for playing videos.

## 1 DCIM/folder/test.mp4 - the video does not plays at all

## 2 DCIM/test.mp4 - it works (plays video) perfect

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String videoPath = intent.getStringExtra("videoPath");

    player = (EasyVideoPlayer) findViewById(R.id.player);
    assert player != null;
    player.setCallback(this);
    player.setSource(Uri.parse(videoPath));
```

Will be glad for any suggestions and good examples.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating how you are playing these videos.

Comment: Thanks for you reply @CommonsWare , i have edited my question, so you can see my code snippet .

Comment: What exactly is the value of `videoPath`? When working with local files, I recommend using `Uri.fromFile()`, where you have used the proper `File` constructors and starting paths (e.g., `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)`) to create a `File` that you know points to the proper location.

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/D:T:21 July 2017/T__4__P__3.mp4

Answer (score 1):

`/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/D:T:21 July 2017/T__4__P__3.mp4` is not a valid `Uri`. It lacks a scheme and it has whitespace.

If you are going to use `Uri.parse()`, you have to use a valid string representation of a `Uri`, one with a scheme (e.g., `file://`) and with whitespace converted (e.g., `%20`).

When working with local files, it is generally safer to use `Uri.fromFile()`, where you have created a `File` that points to the correct location. Among other things, you can check to see if the file is there. When working with external storage, the user can delete the file whenever the user wants, and so you should be confirming its existence before trying to play it back. `Uri.fromFile()`, AFAIK, will convert whitespace in paths for you, and it automatically sets up the `file` scheme.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply,
`player.setSource(Uri.fromFile(new File(videoPath)));`
i have changed my code like this, but video still doesn`t playing

Comment: @GiorgiAsaturyan: What does the `Uri` look like that you get from `Uri.fromFile(new File(videoPath))`? Have you tried calling `exists()` on the `File` to see if the file exists at that path?

Comment: yes, i am checking it manually in my file explorer , and file is really exists . when i am trying it to move out of folder, i mean in the root of DCIM - it works

Comment: maybe the folders in DCIm have some permissions to access?

Comment: @GiorgiAsaturyan: "i am checking it manually in my file explorer" -- I recommend testing it from your code. "maybe the folders in DCIm have some permissions to access?" -- the permissions are the same as for `DCIM` itself (i.e., you need `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, including runtime permissions on Android 6.0+).

Comment: i have checked it from code also and the path of video is correct

Comment: @GiorgiAsaturyan: What does the `Uri` look like that you get from `Uri.fromFile(new File(videoPath))`?

Comment: file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/D%3AT%3A23%20July%202017/T__3__P__3.mp4

Comment: Try a different directory name, one without colons and spaces, and see if you have better luck.

Comment: @GiorgiAsaturyan so `videoPath = "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/D%3AT%3A23%20July%202017/T__‌​3__P__3.mp4"` doesn't work?

Comment: nope (, i am also tried move my mp4 to DCIM/Retrica folder, and it also works great, but from my folder it does not works, maybe i am creating folder wrong ? ! what do you think?

Comment: _"Maybe I am creating folder wrong?"_ Check [**this link**](https://superuser.com/a/693819) for an idea why colons and other symbols are not used in filenames (it's not just on Windows).

Comment: @VC.One - Thanks a lot, the link helped me out, i have replaced ":" to "_" symbol and it works now.

Comment: Where should I replace : to _ in the path   file:///storage/emulated/0/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/202209_03-142653rangeela.mp4